# Android Firebase: onDisconnect is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am using below to update the user status, when internet is disconnected or user will kill the application. Below code is working fine with iOS. But in Android, its updated status on Firebase.

```
 var amOnline = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
                var userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + resObject.id + '/status');
                amOnline.on('value', function (snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.val()) {
                        userRef.onDisconnect().set(false);
                        userRef.set(true);
                    }
                });
                userRef.onDisconnect()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What isn't working about the code? How did you test this?